# Proof verification of a sequence limit

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Show that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{6n-5\cos(n)}{2n-1}=3 $$

We need to find such $n_0\in \text{(Natural numbers)}$ that for every $\epsilon \in \text{(Real numbers)}$ there exists $n_0$ such that $n_0 < n$ for every $n \in \text{(Natural numbers)}$ and that $|a_n - a|<\epsilon$

$$|\frac{6n-5\cos(n)}{2n-1} - 3|<\epsilon$$
$$|\frac{6n-5\cos(n) -6n + 3}{2n-1}|<\epsilon$$
$$|\frac{-5\cos(n)+3}{2n-1}|<\epsilon$$
$$|\frac{-5\cos(n)}{2n-1}|+|\frac{3}{2n-1}|<\epsilon$$
$$ |\frac{-5*1}{2n-1}|+\frac{3}{2n-1}\leq|\frac{-5\cos(n)}{2n-1}|+\frac{3}{2n-1}<\epsilon$$
$$\frac{|-5*1|}{|2n-1|}+\frac{3}{2n-1}< \epsilon$$
$$\frac{5}{2n-1}+\frac{3}{2n-1}< \epsilon$$
$$8<\epsilon*2n-\epsilon$$
$$\frac{8+\epsilon}{2\epsilon} < n \implies n_0 = [\frac{8+\epsilon}{2\epsilon}] + 1$$

Comment: How did you separate $|-5\cos(n) +3|$ in the 3rd line?

Comment: I think you're on the wrong side of the road from the third line to the fourth, triangle inequality goes the other direction

Comment: @FormerMath We know that  $\frac{3}{2n-1}$ is always positive and is thus the same as it's absolute value

Comment: @Former Because -6n+ 6n = 0

Comment: Also: are you trying to merely find $n_0$ or are you trying to prove the claim? because they are two different processes.

Comment: @Simone prove the claim

Comment: @BiliDebili ok, so in that case, after you've found the suitable $n_0$, you must assume that $n \gt n_0$ and then deduce that $|a_n - 3| \lt \epsilon$

Comment: Also : $|-5|$ is BIGGER than $|-5 \cos n |$, not smaller.

Answer (score 3):

Observe that
$$
\left|\frac{3-5\cos(n)}{2n-1}\right|\le \frac{3+|5\cos(n)|}{2n-1}\le \frac{8}{2n-1}\tag{1}
$$
In order the find $n_0$, work with
$$
\frac{8}{2n-1}<\epsilon\tag{2}
$$

Note that (2) *implies*
$$
\left|\frac{3-5\cos(n)}{2n-1}\right|<\epsilon
$$

Answer (score 1):

The idea of your proof is ok, but you should put but implications between inequalities so everyone keeps track of what's going on. Also, you can make it simpler if you observe right from the start that it is equivalent to show that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{3- 5 \cos n}{2n -1} = 0.
$$

Also, if you note that $\left| \dfrac{3- 5 \cos n}{2n -1}\right| \leq \frac{8}{2n-1}$, you can pull this off just by showing that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{8}{2n-1} = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

If I may, a few observations:

Merely finding a suitable $n_0$ is not a proof of the claim, keep in mind the logic: for all $\epsilon \gt 0$ there is an $n_0$ such that, for all naturals $n$:

IF $n \gt n_0$ THEN $|a_n -3| \lt \epsilon$.

So what you must do in order to prove the claim is (after finding a suitable $n_0$): assume that $n \gt n_0$ and then **deduce** that $|a_n -3| \lt \epsilon$.

also:

By triangle inequality we have: $|\frac{-5\cos(n)+3}{2n-1}| \le |\frac{-5\cos(n)}{2n-1}|+|\frac{3}{2n-1}|$ and not the other way around. But it's true that $|\frac{3-5\cos(n)}{2n-1}| \ge |\frac{3}{2n-1}|-|\frac{5\cos(n)}{2n-1}|$.

Lastly: $|-5|$ is bigger than $|-5\cos n|$, not smaller.